# How can I use Environment.newLine for Newtonsoft.Json.Compact?

Tags: c#, json, compact-framework

I am developing JSON parse by Newtonsoft.Json.Compact  in the .net compact framework 2.0

Environment.newLine is showing an undefined Error occurred during JSON parse.

```
 JObject obj = JObject.Parse(jsonData);
 JArray array = JArray.Parse(obj["result"].ToString()); // Error
```

How can I use Environment.newLine   for Newtonsoft.Json.Compact ?

help me plz..

Comment: Please share jsonData, so that I can replicate the problem and fix it for you. 
Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for your comment. but it is not json data problem  .This error occurred any json data

Comment: If you are getting an exception, post the whole exception content, including the stack trace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.NET Compact Framework 2.0 does not support `Environment.NewLine`, you're probably using a version of `Newtonsoft.Json.Compact` for a different platform, and this happens the first problem it runs in to.